# Why does Update Policy in Azure Data Explorer apply on combination of extents on source table? Can we limit this to run on a single extent at a time?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The query in the update policy we are using has a limitation that it works fine on a small count of rows only. The rate of ingestion to this source table is controlled appropriately. Also, have edited the sharding policy to allow only a limited rowCount.  However, the update starts failing when the update policy is applied on multiple extents at once.

```
Failed to invoke update policy. Target Table = 'settings', Query = 'let raw_config3 = 
__table("raw_config3", 'All', 'AllButRowStore') 
| where extent_id() in (guid(58b4a126-8ff2-4c04-a8f8-d6be2629c865), guid(10d66fec-5146-4d63-b3db-d15ba52244b9), guid(8bc99805-9dcd-43ed-8133-402ba77eb566), guid(8127f67e-8d20-4096-bf46-f3736c77ecd5));
getBiosSettings()': Semantic error: 'let raw_config3 = 
__table("raw_config3", 'All', 'AllButRowStore') 
| where extent_id() in (guid(58b4a126-8ff2-4c04-a8f8-d6be2629c865), guid(10d66fec-5146-4d63-b3db-d15ba52244b9), guid(8bc99805-9dcd-43ed-8133-402ba77eb566), guid(8127f67e-8d20-4096-bf46-f3736c77ecd5));
getBiosSettings()' has the following semantic error: SEM0100: 'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Path'.
```

Is it an expected scenario for the update policy to be applied on a combination of extents? Can that be configured in any way?

Edit 1-
Adding some context on what we are trying to achieve.
We have a multi level xml data dumped as a single field in the source table. The update policy uses a query to extract some information from this field and store it as separate rows in the target table. As the xml data is multiple leves deep and contains array fields, we need to use mv expand and bag unpack in the said query. This breaks when the input data is bigger than a certain amount.

Tried to limit the extent size for the source table using MaxRowCount. However, the update policy applies the query on multiple extents together. Is there a way to configure this behavior?

Is it a bad practice to have a heavy query (as described above) in the update policy?

Edit 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------

My understanding is that for some update to the source table, the update policy should be applied **once**.  My observation was different though. Explaining the repro of the scenario -

There is a source table 'Source', we ingest data in this every 10 minutes, in batches of 5 entries. There is an update policy configured to simply copy the same to a target table named Target. And there is a update policy to record the count of data the policy runs on each time and the same is stored in Target2.

Given we are sending equal amount of data every 10 minutes, my expectation was to see constant value in Target2 and for each unique row we send, I expect one record in Target.

Setup Commands -

```
.create table Source(Turn : string, Batch: string, Data: string )

.create table Target(Turn : string, Batch: string, Data: string )

.create table Target2(Count: long )

.create function copySource(){ Source }

.alter table Target policy update 
@'[{"IsEnabled": true,  "Source": "Source", "Query": "copySource()", "IsTransactional": false}]'

.create function copySourceWithCount() { Source | count  }

.alter table Target2 policy update 
@'[{"IsEnabled": true,  "Source": "Source", "Query": "copySourceWithCount()", "IsTransactional": false}]'
```

The count of records on which update policy runs on keeps increasing regularly instead of being constant-

```
Target2 
| extend ingestion_time()
| order by $IngestionTime asc
```

```
Count   $IngestionTime
    5   2020-09-27T10:03:50.3236393Z
    10  2020-09-27T10:26:52.8994856Z
    15  2020-09-27T10:37:04.2836551Z
    20  2020-09-27T10:47:05.638047Z
```

The number of records in the target table for each ingestion to source table too keeps changing. The data ingested earlier has higher number of occurrences in the target table -

```
Target
| summarize count() by Turn, Batch, Data
| where Turn contains "b"
| order by count_ desc
```

```
Turn Batch Data Count
    b   0   0   5
    b   0   1   5
    b   0   2   5
    b   0   3   5
    b   0   4   5
    b   1   0   4
    b   1   1   4
    b   1   2   4
    b   1   3   4
    b   1   4   4
    b   2   0   3
    b   2   1   3
    b   2   2   3
    b   2   3   3
    b   2   4   3
    b   3   0   2
    b   3   1   2
    b   3   2   2
    b   3   3   2
    b   3   4   2
    b   4   0   1
    b   4   1   1
    b   4   2   1
    b   4   3   1
    b   4   4   1
```

From this, it seems, the update policy runs on same same data multiple times. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

An update policy runs on a batch of data being ingested in a single ingestion operation.

- Depending on the amount of records in that batch, and on the value of the `MaxRowCount` property in the effective sharding policy.
- That batch may span across more than 1 data shard (extent).
- However, unless your query makes an assumption on the amount of input extents (which it shouldn't), that shouldn't lead to any failures.

At first glance, the semantic error shown in your original message doesn't relate to the number of source extents, rather to the query itself - `Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Path'.`.

- If you could share the activity ID for the failure, and the content of the function named `getBiosSettings()`, we may be able to help you figure out the actual root cause.

Comment: The query we are using included using the bag_unpack plugin a couple of times and that breaks when the input data is bigger than a particular amount.

Comment: Edited the question to add some context on what we are trying to achieve. Repeating the question here, is it a bad practice to have a heavy query in the update policy?

Comment: The error you've written is a semantic error, which results from the combination of the logic in your update query, and the dynamic contents/schema of your data. Reducing the amount of data per ingestion operation isn't likely to solve it - you should make sure the logic in your function operates on a 'stable' output schema, and doesn't make assumptions about the contents of the source data, that can change between one ingestion batch to another.

Comment: I understand I can edit the query to make it more robust. However, I have verified that the query runs fine for 10 entries of a data and breaks on 20 entries of the same data [exact same rows sent repeatedly]. The bag_unpack plugin breaks and this is probably because there is a LOW_MEOMORY CONDITION when there is large input data.
Given the size of the data in a row and the processing required is considerable, I am trying to try this out with lesser amount of input data.

Comment: Also I suspect the input data is growing larger than expected due to some reason the update policy works. Hence trying to understand that. Have added to the question the scenario where the update policy makes the query run on same data multiple times  and hence larger amount of data than expected. Can you take a look and let me know if that is an expected behaviour?

Comment: I would recommend that you open a support ticket for your resource. The repro details you provided are only partial, and don't include a main piece - the data being ingested to the source table. A support ticket will help capture all necessary details

Comment: That makes sense. Let me do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Yoni wrote, the error you receive is not related to the fact that multiple extents are processed together as part of the update policy.

The error says `'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Path'`. From what I understand from your question, sometimes you get this error and sometimes you don't. It means that the schema of your query isn't deterministic because you have `evaluate pivot`, `evaluate bag_unpack` or something similar in your query, and in some cases, the `Path` column is not produced.

If this is a problem with the data that's ingested, then you'll have to fix it.
However, if it's expected that sometimes the Path column won't be there, then you can use [`column_ifexists(Path, "DefaultValue")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists).

Comment: Thanks, the query uses bag_unpack and it breaks when the amount of input data is bigger than a particular amount that leads to this error. So I was trying to limit the input data by using MaxRowCount in the sharding policy. We are alos sending the data in a controlled slow rate. But it looks like the update policy applies on multiple extents at a time. And that means bigger data and the query breaks then